# Is this the correct way to use @classmethod?

Tags: python

```
class CityNameMapping(object):
    CITY_NAME_MAPPING = {}

    with open('data/city.csv', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        if not data.startswith("#"):
            city_entry = data.split('\t')
            CITY_NAME_MAPPING[city_entry[1]] = city_entry[0]

    @classmethod
    def get_mapping(cls, city):
        if city in cls.CITY_NAME_MAPPING:
            return cls.CITY_NAME_MAPPING[city]
        else:
            print("No city name found: {} ".format(city))
            return None
```

This function is supposed to map a city name from one form to another form, i.e. from Japanese written form to English written form. Example:

```
Nagoya  名古屋市
```

I defined a global variable CITY_NAME_MAPPING, and then use a class method to access it. Also, Does this ensure the file will be loaded only once, if this function is called again?

Comment: Your `@classmethod get_mapping()` seems fine, but myself, I would move the code that reads the `.csv` file into its own function and call it: `CITY_NAME_MAPPING = read_city_csv()`

Answer (score 1):

File will be loaded once you test add print statement while reading file in order to test it. `CITY_NAME_MAPPING` can also be accessed without classmethod.(self.CITY_NAME_MAPPING)